# Split columns Pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, igraph

I have a Pd.Dataframe that is generated by Igraph, I am wondering how to have a cleaner table:

What I have:

```
degree
(igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f894149fe50>, 5, {'name': 8}), 20)
(igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f894149fe50>, 6, {'name': 9}), 8)
(igraph.Vertex(<igraph.Graph object at 0x7f894149fe50>, 34, {'name': 45}), 8)
...
```

And I just want the degree of freedom and centrality value:

```
node   centrality
8      20
9      8
45     8
...
```

Thank you soo much.

Comment: How did you create the dataframe?

Comment: That was from OrderedDict()

Comment: ```def degree_centrality(graph):
    centrality_dict=OrderedDict()
    score_list=graph.degree()
    centrality_dict['degree']=sorted([(graph.vs[i],score_list[i]) for i in range(0,len(score_list))],key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(centrality_dict)```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted([(n['name'], c) for n, c in zip(g.vs, g.degree())],
                         reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1]),
                  columns=['node', 'centrality'])
```

---

**Old answer**

Modify your function:

```
def degree_centrality(graph):
    score_list = graph.degree()
    data = sorted([(graph.vs[i]['name'], score_list[i])
                       for i in range(0,len(score_list))],
                  key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['node', 'centrality'])
    return df

df = degree_centrality(g)
```

Sample of output:

```
>>> df
  node  centrality
0    C           4
1    A           3
2    D           3
3    F           3
4    E           2
5    G           2
6    B           1
```